# Delivery method based on condition? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, development-environment

Rails 4.1.4, I have many classes of Mailers, and they all have different delivery methods. Now this has caused me a problem.

In development and test environment when I have delivery_method as `:test` then if I perform and delivery using the below class then the delivery method becomes `:custom_method`, even though I have mentioned `config.delivery_method = :test` in the rails environment files.

```
class CustomMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default :delivery_method => :custom_method,
          from: "...",
          reply_to: '...'

  def emailer(emails)
    mail(to: emails, subject: 'test')
  end

end
```

What is the right way of changing the `:custom_method` to `:test` in development and test environments ?

One possible solution I have implemented which works is this:

```
class CustomMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  DELIVERY_METHOD = Rails.env == 'production' ? :custom_method : :test

  default :delivery_method => DELIVERY_METHOD,
          from: "...",
          reply_to: '...'

  def emailer(emails)
    mail(to: emails, subject: 'test')
  end

end
```

This works for me but I feel this is not a good way because I have to write this line:

```
DELIVERY_METHOD = Rails.env == 'production' ? :custom_method : :test
```

in every Mailer class and that can cause redundancy. Would be great if it could be handled in some common way.

Please note that there are **different** delivery methods for every Mailer class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach you're taking certainly works, but I believe that querying Rails.env in your code is an anti-pattern.

You could instead use the application configuration by setting a [custom config attribute](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration). Here's an example:

```
# config/production.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  # by having this configured by an environment variable 
  # you can have different values in staging, 
  # develop, demo, etc.. They all use "production" env.
  config.x.mailer_livemode = ENV['MAILER_LIVEMODE']
end

# config/development.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.x.mailer_livemode = false
end

# config/test.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.x.mailer_livemode = false
end

# app/mailers/custom_mailer.rb
default delivery_method: Rails.application.config.x.mailer_livemode ? :custom_method : :test
```

The flexibility is superior. You can have more that one configuration variables working together, set the `delivery_method` straight in config, etc.

Most importantly, you don't rely on something irrelevant (the Rails.env) for something that concerns how your emails are sent.

Comment: Much better approach.

Answer (score 0):

How about create an ApplicationMailer and get all other mailers to inherit from ApplicationMailer? This is the approach in Rails5 now. Code below shows one possible way to define delivery method in children mailers and inherit the selection logic from ApplicationMailer.

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  SELECTOR = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = k }
  DELIVERY_METHOD = Rails.env.production? ? :custom_method : :test ##selection logic, use: env, env variables ...
end

class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  SELECTOR[:custom_method] = :sendmail  ##class-specific delivery method
  default delivery_method: SELECTOR[DELIVERY_METHOD]
  ##....
end
```

Comment: the `:custom method` is not common for those classes which are going to be inherited

Comment: Of course. You define custom methods in children classes,  not in ApplicationMailer.

Comment: then whats the use of inheriting from ApplicationMailer when nothing is common in them , I understand it could be a good practice but it doesn't solve the my problem, its basically the same thing which I have already mentioned the solution in my question, inheriting it from a class won't make any difference as I will still have to write that code multiple times.

Comment: i assumed that you had a way to resolve `:custom_method` in each mailers, didn't realize you meant it to be replaced with a concrete method in actual code. I've edited my answer to provide one possible implementation.